# On the word formation of »beschweren«

Tags: etymology, morphology

I am wondering in which way ***beschweren*** ( as in *sich beschweren*) is derived:

> 1. be-schwer-en, where the root is the adj. ***schwer***

or

> 2. be- Schwere-n, where the root is the noun ***Schwere***

---

This question involves elements of both etymology and morphology. My major intent lies in an etymological interpretation of the lexical meaning of ***sich beschweren***. On the other hand, such an etymological approach to lexical meaning is grounded upon morphological facts in this case, so morphological arguments will be as welcome as those of etymology.

Comment: I just noticed a little discrepancy: Your questions looks, as if you were asking about [*morphology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29), whilst it is tagged with [*etymology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology). Would you please clarify this?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Thanks for your reminder. This question involves elements of both etymology and morphology. My major intent lies in interpretation of the lexical meaning of ,,sich beschweren", hence i labelled this question as one of etymology. Then you reminded me that such interpretation is grounded upon morphological facts, so I added the tag 'morphology'.

Answer (score 3):

Among other features, [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/index_en.html) offers the analysis of the word formation (*Wortbildung*).

You can find the analysis of the verb *beschweren* here:

It is your first version:

> *be* + *schwer* + *en*

Looking at your second version, [*Schwere*](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/schwere:N:F) itself is formed by adding a suffix to the adjective (*aka* suffixation):

> *schwer* + *e*

**Edit** to add etymological information:

In Althochdeutsch, [swārī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swari#Etymology) (*Schwere*) is a female noun, which derived from the adjective [swār](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swar#Old_High_German) (*schwer*).
The latter one derived from Proto-Germanic *swēraz.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/beschweren#et-1) lists the etymologic development of *beschweren* and states that it belongs to the adjective *schwer*:

> **beschweren** Vb. ‘belasten’,
>
> ahd. *biswāren* ‘bedrücken, belasten’ (10. Jh.),
>
> mhd. *beswæren* ‘bedrücken, belästigen, betrüben’
>
> gehört wie das gleichbed. Simplex ahd. *swāren* (8. Jh.) zu dem unter ↗schwer (s. d.) behandelten Adjektiv.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is asking for the etymology of "beschweren" - that's why I gave -1 here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach "beschweren" is derived from "schwer", see [here for example](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beschweren#Etymology). What more would you expect?

Comment: I'd think, in this case, the english wiktionary gives the morphological information not the etymological.  Canoo, too, has the morphological analysis, not the etymological. The question asks pretty clearly whether "beschweren" comes from "schwer" or from "Schwere". Your answer does not provide any information on that.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach The questions pretty clearly asks for both, etymology _and_ morphology.

Comment: Sorry, "My major intent lies in an etymological interpretation of the lexical meaning of sich beschweren. On the other hand, such an etymological approach to lexical meaning is grounded upon morphological facts in this case, so morphological arguments will be as welcome as those of etymology." To my eye that clearly asks for etymology, accepting morphological arguments. Anyway, I tried to withdraw the -1 since it might not be as clear as I primarily thought - but it's not possible any more.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I added some further information (maybe that is why you couldnt change). Hope The answer satisfies both aspects more clearly now

Comment: I changed my vote from -1 to +1

Answer (score 2):

The root of the term (sich zu) "beschweren" is the noun: **Beschwer**, die (article feminine).
The noun **Beschwer** is a jurisdictional term which colloquial meaning in German is: Last, Beschwerung, Nachteil (burden,loading, disadvantage, hindrance, harm).
A "Beschwer" is a jurisdictional negative decision or claim against a person.

(sich zu) beschwer*en* (verb) means "to complain" against someone or something (verb).

(Eine) Beschwer*de* (noun,fem.) means "complaint" (noun)

**Edit**: Thank you for the question! The root word is: *schwer* (adj.) which originates from the Old High German word: swaren. The word **Beschweren** (vb.) originates from the Old High German words: *biswaren* and biswarida . It then evolved in to the Middle High German word: *beswaeren*. Which means (directly translated) "to make something heavier".

Comment: We may have to add that the noun *die Beschwer* is no longer used outside of jurisdiction.

Comment: And the [morphological root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29) of *Beschwer* is...?

Comment: @Marzipanherz wild guess it's *Schwere*, the noun

Comment: @MarcusMüller According to my resources, *Schwere* is a *Suffigierung* of the adjective *schwer* as well.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Feels like Althochdeutsch *swārī*, which I think is a noun

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found that [*swārī*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swari#Etymology) is indeed a female noun in Althochdeutsch, which derived from the adjective [*swār*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swar#Old_High_German)

Comment: @Marzipanherz ah, that makes sense! Yeah, so, then it's all clearer to me.